# How to turn on FastParse option in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

The book that I purchased to help with my SSIS understanding seems to have glossed over this, and I wanted to know exactly what is the method to turn on FastParse in SSIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set fast parse (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139833.aspx))

1. Right-click the Flat File source or Data Conversion transformation, and then click Show Advanced Editor.
2. In the Advanced Editor dialog box, click the Input and Output Properties tab.
3. In the Inputs and Outputs pane, click the column for which you want to enable fast parse.
4. In the Properties window, expand the Custom Properties node, and then set the FastParse property to True.
5. Click OK.