# SSIS Not saving correct Month and Day fields from CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, csv, ssis

I have a flat file that I intend to import into a table via SSIS. The file has a field with dates in the format "d/mm/yyyy". These dates eventually get stored into the Database as "yyyy/mm/dd". I know this because I run a datepart sql query on the table data to find out. I have no problem with how they are stored as I can format them via presentation.
The problem is that for some of the dates, the days are swapped with the month values. ie "3/05/1989" should be stored as "1989/05/03", but it can end up as "1989/03/05" and as such, the data presentation is inconsistent with what is in the CSV files.
I have searched everywhere possible for a solution and trust me I can put the links here if you want. I tried exporting from one csv file to another csv file, that one saved "d/mm/yyyy" the same way "d/mm/yyyy".
My last attempt was this 
[Date format issue while importing from a flat file to an SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315471/date-format-issue-while-importing-from-a-flat-file-to-an-sql-database)
And as you can see, it hasn't still been marked as an answer. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Use `Substring` to extract  date ,month and year in Derived transformation

Comment: Thanks praveen, but as you can see I am a bit of a noob here. Can you point me in the right direction with a small example?

Comment: You need to start with two things: 1. Open your CSV in a TEXT editor (not excel) and observe what the data REALLY looks like. 2. Post the data type that you are loading the dates into - is it `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after searching around this is what worked for me:
1.  I used a Derived column transformation to transform the date field and split the date string by using the solution here: [SSIS How to get part of a string by separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921645/ssis-how-to-get-part-of-a-string-by-separator) .
Am surprised it hasnt been marked as an answer.

2. Since I knew my db will switch the day and month regardless, I switched them myself and passed the result back to the same field in the Derived column transformation like so:
   TOKEN(FlightDate,"/",2) + "/" + TOKEN(FlightDate,"/",1) + "/" + TOKEN(FlightDate,"/",3)
   where 2 is the month, 1 is the day and 3 is the year.

Now the results are being saved in the correct manner and so the presentation matches the source.
I know there should be a better way to do this but this works for me and I hope it works for anyone else who finds themselves in my situation

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell the structure of the Destination table?There should not be any problem while converting the d/mm/yyyy formats into yyyy/mm/dd.Let me know the datatype and then i can help you in further resolution of the problem.

Comment: The datatype is date, and for the structure of the table it doesnt realy matter as any table with a date field produces the same results here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have date in this format `d/MM/yyyy` then you can use the below expression to convert string to date

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(Right([DATE],4) + "/" + 
SUBSTRING([DATE],FINDSTRING( [DATE], "/", 1) +1 , FINDSTRING( [DATE], "/", 2) -1)
+ "/" + substring( [DATE],1,FINDSTRING( [DATE], "/", 1) -1 ) )
```